# Retrieving values from an Insert that called a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

There are two tables `items`and `items_history`, after an insert occurs in the `items`table I'm looking to insert an entry into the `items_history`table using the below trigger.

I'm a little confused and concerned I'm not doing it correctly, I'm creating two variables `NEW.iid`and `NEW.ip` these are both values inserted on the insert that called the trigger. Am I doing it correctly to get the two values and insert them into the `items_history` table or is there a better more efficient way to do it?

`iid` on the `items_history`table is a FOREIGN KEY of `id` on the `items`tables.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `item_created_trg`;
CREATE TRIGGER `item_created_trg`
AFTER INSERT ON `items` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     SET NEW.iid = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM `items` LIMIT 1);
     SET NEW.ip = (SELECT created_ip FROM `items` i WHERE i.id=NEW.iid LIMIT 1);
     INSERT INTO `items_history` (iid, title, description, created, created_by, created_ip) VALUES (NEW.iid, 'Added to database.', '', NOW(), 1, NEW.ip);
END;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly your trigger should look like this

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER item_created_trg
AFTER INSERT ON items
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO items_history (iid, title, description, created, created_by, created_ip)
  VALUES (NEW.id, 'Added to database.', '', NOW(), 1, NEW.created_ip);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f53d2/1)** demo

Comment: Thanks for that, can the NEW syntax be used to call values from the INSERT that called the trigger?